# How to intercept additional response parameters from the backend?

Tags: javascript, extjs

When adding, changing or deleting records from the store, I return `{success: true|false}`. But in some conditions I want to return an additional message (exampl `{success: true, hello: 'world'}`) from the backend and show it in the alert window. But [store write event](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.7.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#event-write) returns operation, where there are only `success`, `exception`, `complete` and other properties, but empty `_request` and `_response`. This is probably a trivial task, but I haven't figured out the operation objects yet. How can I get to the response to read additional parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to achieve this.

Lets focus on the store.
This depends if its a proxy store or buffered store.

In first case, use the load event for example. Or if its buffered, use the prefetch event.

Here is an example.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            proxy, // set properly
            listeners: {
                load: (store, records, success, operation) => {
                  let response = operation.getResponse();
              // now you can access responseJson or responseText and decode it - depends on your ext version and proxy config
                }
            }
        });
```